# How much "one-time fee" do I have to pay to be able to use PayPal to send money?

Tags: fees, online-payment, ecommerce, paypal

From http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/smallbusiness/webhosting/sitebuilder2/paypal/paypal-04.html:

> Personal accounts are meant for use by individuals. With a Personal
>   account, you can send and receive money for free, but you cannot
>   receive payments funded by debit or credit cards. (Note: Members
>   located outside the U.S. will pay a one-time fee before they can send
>   money.)

I live outside the United States. Does anyone know how much "one-time fee" I would have to pay to be able to use PayPal to send money?

Comment: You quote that excerpt from Yahoo!'s site.  Why not check on Paypal's site?  Besides, the link there doesn't go to a specific answer anymore.  It could be a stale link.

Comment: becuse paypal purposely makes it unclear: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-fees-outside . after reading that i still can't anwer my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to what you're looking for in the [PayPal Help Center](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/helpweb?cmd=_help).

Refer specifically to the question [PayPal - How much do you charge to my card when confirming my debit or credit card?](https://www.paypal.com/helpcenter/main.jsp?cmd=_help&serverInstance=9012&t=solutionTab&ft=searchTab&ps=solutionPanels&solutionId=12603&isSrch=Yes).  Quote:

> We take the extra step to confirm your card so that we can verify that the
>   card is valid and that you are the card owner.
>
> To confirm your card, we’ll charge $1.95 to it. After the card is confirmed,
>   we’ll refund the amount to your PayPal balance.
>
> Here are amounts for cards in other countries:
>
> - $ 2.45 CAD
> - € 1.50 EUR
> - 1.00 GBP
> - 200 JPY
> - 2.00 AUD
> - 3.00 NZD
> - 3.00 CHF
> - 15.00 HKD
> - 15.00 SEK
> - 12.50 DKK
> - 6.50 PLN
> - 15.00 NOK
> - 400.00 HUF
> - 50.00 CZK
> - 4.00 BRL
> - 10.00 MYR
> - 20.00 MXN
> - 8.00 ILS
> - 100.00 PHP
> - 70.00 TWD
> - 70.00 THB
>
> If we can’t determine or don’t support your card’s currency, we charge
>   $1.95 USD to the card.

*(Refer directly to PayPal for potentially more up-to-date information.)*

Answer (score 0):

The fees for the services are displayed on the PayPal website at

https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_display-fees-outside

Is there anything else you were looking for.

Comment: your link didn't state the amt of "one-time fee" required before a person outside US can send money..